# Formatting int with decimals PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm have this number

```
55550
```

But I it should be 555.50, I tried number_format() and sprinft but did not work.

Comment: Divide the number by 100?

Comment: What is your code that outputs that wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$num = 55550;
$num = (float) $num / 100;

echo number_format($num, 2, ".", "");
```

by casting the number to float, and dividing by 100 you can use number_format to change the format.